# Can't configure Visual Studio Code to use C++14 standard (C++03 standard is used even though I changed some settings)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++03

I did a very simple app that works when I build and run it from the terminal by:

```
g++ -std=c++14 helloworld.cpp
./a.out
```

Now I'm trying to configure the Visual Studio Code to debug this app. I did:

- Settings -> search for "cppStandard" -> changed to c++14 for both User & Workspace
- Add Debug configuration -> C/C++: g++ build and debug active file
- Select -> Debug C/C++ file.
  error showing:
  `'function\<void ()\>' is deprecated: Using std::function in C++03 is not supported anymore. Please upgrade to C++11 or later, or use a different type \[-Wdeprecated-declarations\]`

The IDE also marks the code:

```
std::function<void()> func = []() { std::cout << "From Thread ID : "<<std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n"; };
```

as an error, showing:

```
class std::__1::function<void ()> 'function<void ()>' is deprecated: Using std::function in C++03 is not supported anymore. Please upgrade to C++11 or later, or use a different type [-Wdeprecated-declarations]gcc
```

Edited:
I'm using macOS Ventura with apple silicon.
I have added c_cpp_properties.json (by: Control+Shift+P -> c/c++ edit configuration).

```
    {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Mac",
                "includePath": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**"
                ],
                "defines": [],
                "macFrameworkPath": [
                    "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
                ],
                "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
                "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64",
                "cppStandard": "c++14"
            }
        ],
        "version": 4
    }
```

I still get the same error about C++03 not compatible with my code, Any suggestions?

Comment: ***Any suggestions?*** Learn what the 3 json files are and which 2 you need to edit to change the default c++ standard. That is unless you are using a build extension like code-runner, CMakeTools or MakeFiletools where you have to make the change in the file(s) used by the extension instead.

Comment: @drescherjm if you mean editing "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++14" in settings.json in two locations (for current project and on User level), that is equivalent to changing this parameter from Settings

Comment: There is `tasks.json`, `c_cpp_properties.json` and `launch.json` you did not mention your OS and compiler so we can't link you to the specific VSCode documentation for your toolchain. If you are using macOS VSCode suggests you to use c++17 and explains the changes in the documentation.